# MS Access - Store VBA Logic on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

This might be a bit of a stretch. I have an MS Access front-end that sits on our SQL Server back-end and uses a mix of VBA and SQL stored procedures to process data.

Several of my VBA procedures dynamically craft a SQL query by stitching together strings and then sending them over to the server to be executed. My question is whether this process can work in the reverse? For example, I set up a method in VBA that pulls a string from a table in the server and then executes it.

To clarify, I know how to use stored procedures to handle logic in the back-end. My goal here is to find a way to pull raw VBA out of a SQL table/store procedure and then run it in Access.

Comment: Munging a bunch of strings together and executing it is a recipe for disaster. Sounds to me like some reworking of some of the architecture would be time well spent.

Comment: @SeanLange Unfortunately I think you're right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but I highly recommend you don't.

You can evaluate simple, single expressions using the `Eval` function in VBA.

You can import and modify modules through `Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents`. Here, you can modify the string contents of a module, but this requires exclusive access and recompiling the database while the code is running (thus I highly recommend you don't do this).

Generally, if you don't need to work with the Access application object, I recommend dynamically creating vbscript files instead, to avoid needing exclusive access and needing to recompile your database.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I guess I'll have to file this under "just because I _could_ doesn't mean I _should_."